# Returning a name from a column using the MAX() function on a different column

Tags: php, mysql

I had a quick question on how to return a certain value from a column after using the MAX() function on a different column. For instance, I am trying to return the full name of the comedian depending on who has the highest number of videos posted on youtube. I am able to get the number of videos posted but I am having trouble returning the name. "countc" is the column keeping track of how many youtube videos a comedian has posted. I am using PHPMyAdmin.

```
<?php

    session_start();
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or die("Could not connect");
    mysqli_select_db($con, 'youtube') or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $output = '';

    $query = " SELECT fullname FROM comedian WHERE MAX(countc) AS vidcount ";
    $query_result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    if($query_result)
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_result))
        {
            $output = "The comedian with the most videos is"." ".$row['vidcount'];
        }
        echo $output;
    }
    else{
        $output = "Could not find top comedian.";
        echo $output;
    }
```

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die(mysqli_error($conn));` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I get you right you want to order your comedians by the highest number of posted YouTube videos.

Try the following ...

```
SELECT fullname, countc FROM comedian ORDER BY countc DESC
```

If you want to limit the result to the number of resultsets you want to have, just append a `LIMIT` to your query.

```
SELECT fullname, countc FROM comedian ORDER BY countc DESC LIMIT 1
```

The above shown example limits the result to a single resultset.

Comment: really? check again.

Comment: should i change it to row['fullname'] in the output statement as well

Comment: Okay just tried this and its giving me a name but its giving me the comedian with the lowest number of videos instead

Comment: Okay I just changed it to ASC and it seems to be working

Comment: Hey Hafsa, you can access everything you selected in your sql statement with `$row['columnname']`. Its important, that the column you want to output was mentionend in your `SELECT` statement. If you 're unsure what 's inside your `$row` array output it with `var_dump($row)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sub query like following :

```
SELECT fullname FROM comedian WHERE countc = (SELECT MAX(countc) FROM comedian);
```